# Proving if $A$ is a symmetric matrix then the Min-Max Theorem identities remain true

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Given that the matrix $A$ is symmetric I am trying to prove that:

$\lambda_k$ $= \max_{\dim(V)=k} \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} v^T A v = \min_{\dim(V)=n-k+1} \max_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} v^T A v$

I have:

Since $A$ is symmetric then $A=U\Lambda U^T $

So by substitution

$= \max_{\dim(V)=k} \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} v^T A v = \max_{\dim(V)=k} \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} v^T U \Lambda U^T v$

By definition of the singular value decomposition of a symmetric matrix, then $U = [v_1 ... v_n] $ eigenvectors and since $\max_{dim(V)=k} $ then

$= \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} v_k^T [v_1 ... v_n] \Lambda [v_1 ... v_n]^T v_k$

Then since $v_1$, ..., $v_n$ are orthogonal

$= \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} [0 ... v_k^2 ... 0] \Lambda [0 ... v_k^2 ... 0]^T $

Since $\|v\|=1$ then

$= \min_{v\epsilon V : \|v\|=1} [0 ... 1 ... 0] \Lambda [0 ... 1 ... 0]^T $

Then finally since $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues then

$= 1\lambda_k$

and I'm thinking a similar argument could be made for the other case. Is my mathematical reasoning sound, or am I making any assumptions in my "proof" that are invalid.